# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE for FireBaseMessaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

In my attempt to upload the latest build of my mobile application (Ionic framework) to playstore, I am forced to updated the targetSDKVersion from 30 to 31 which results in plenty of issues with PendingIntent. Most of which I have manage to resolve by utilizing  `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`
to replace `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or 0` when PendingIntent is being used.

However, there is this particular error with the Pending Intent which I suspect is related to the MyFirebaseMessagingService.java file but it is only being declared and not actually used. How do I go about solving the issue in this case?

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
package com.gae.scaffolder.plugin;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FCMPlugin";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.d(TAG, "New token: " + token);
        FCMPlugin.sendTokenRefresh(token);
    }

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        Log.d(TAG, "==> MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived");
        
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Message: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("wasTapped", false);
        
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
            data.put("title", remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            data.put("body", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        for (String key : remoteMessage.getData().keySet()) {
            Object value = remoteMessage.getData().get(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "\tKey: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            data.put(key, value);
        }
        
        Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Data: " + data.toString());
        FCMPlugin.sendPushPayload(data);
    }
    // [END receive_message]
}
```

**Error Message**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-MyFirebaseMessagingService
Process: ----- , PID: 16071
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: -----: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:408)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:491)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:477)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:441)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzf(Unknown Source:68)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc.zzas(Unknown Source:34)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source:59)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.run(Unknown Source:2)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Comment: Are you sure you updated the Firebase messaging service dependency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of this issue is to update the `cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated` plugin.

This can be achieved by

1. Deleting the existing `cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated` plugin
2. Removing the android platform
3. Installing the forked version of the plugin where the issue has been resolved
4. Rebuilding the android platform

https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/issues/293#issuecomment-1377487961